# Если словосочетание не найдено, то делать поиск по словам из этого словосочетания в sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Как в sql осуществить поиск по словам из предложения если предложение полностью не найдено?

Comment: разбиваешь предложения на слова и делаешь LIKE

Comment: полнотекстовый поиск использовать